# Error Running Meteor: /mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, meteor

When starting the Meteor project (initially created on a Windows 10 system) on Mac OS X using

```
meteor
```

the following error appears

```
line 135: exec: /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.fpzmec++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: 
cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Is this error happening because it was originally created in Windows?

If so, how can a OSX system work on the project without causing any problems when the Windows 10 system needs to run the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter where the project was created, because everything under

```
.meteor/local
```

Is built dynamically. This directory should be in your .meteor/.gitignore file to prevent it going into your git repo.

If .meteor/local was copied from the Windows machine, do a

```
rm -rf .meteor/local
```

And try again.

You also need to check that you have all the pre-requisites installed on your Mac, ie XCode, Java, Android Studio, and a valid AVD for your target platform